# Why is my answer to the Two Sum problem failing with [3,2,3]?

Tags: python

Can't figure out why this code fails with [3,2,3] as the input. My code is not recognizing the index of the last "3" in the list and not sure what to change.

```
def twoSum(nums = [3, 2, 3], target = 9):
    count = 0
    target_i = []

    for index, num in enumerate(nums):
        for i in nums:
            for j in nums:

                if i + j == target and nums.index(i) != nums.index(j):
                    count += 1    
                    if count == 1:  
                        target_i.append(nums.index(i))
                        target_i.append(nums.index(j))
                      
                        return target_i

print(twoSum())
```

Comment: share the exact error details please.

Comment: Presumably you are wondering why `[3, 2, 3].index(3)` always returns 0 and never 2, but I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve so can't suggest a fix.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right inputs? There are no two numbers in ```[3, 2, 3]``` that add up to 9.

Comment: `index()` always returns the index of the first occurrence. If there are duplicate values in the list, you'll never get the index of the second one.

Comment: You should be able to solve this with only 2 `for` loops. Hint: start the inner loop 1 after the index of the outer loop.

Comment: If this is the classic two sum problem it's worth noting there's a way to solve this with one loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`nums.index()` always returns the index of the first occurrence, so you can't get the index of the second `3`. Use `enumerate` in both loops (and you don't need the outer loop at all).

And if you want to ensure that the two indexes are different, start the inner loop after the current element of the outer loop.

```
def twoSum(nums = [3, 2, 3], target = 9):
    for i, num1 in enumerate(nums):
        for j, num2 in enumerate(nums[i+1:], i+1):
            if num1 + num2 == target:
                return [i, j]
```

There's no need for the `count` variable, since you're returning as soon as you find the first matching sum. And you can just make the list that you're returning a literal, rather than appending to a list.

Comment: With proper `index()` usage it not only *works* but is also *faster* than  with `enumerate`.

Comment: See demo in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask the `index` function to search the second number **after** the first one, by giving it the start index as second argument. Also, you're calling your function without arguments and the default arguments don't have a solution, so no wonder you didn't find one.

The whole thing cleaner, also using a [list display](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#list-displays) (not a [literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming))), code based on Barman's:

```
def twoSum(nums = [3, 2, 3], target = 6):
    for i, num1 in enumerate(nums):
        for num2 in nums[i+1:]:
            if num1 + num2 == target:
                return [i, nums.index(num2, i + 1)]
```

Benchmark along with Barman's:

```
small default case:
 620 ns   633 ns   634 ns   647 ns   658 ns  twoSum_Barry_Manilow
 564 ns   570 ns   579 ns   588 ns   595 ns  twoSum_Right_Said_Fred

n=5000 case:
1091 ms  1093 ms  1095 ms  1098 ms  1125 ms  twoSum_Barry_Manilow
 734 ms   735 ms   736 ms   737 ms   741 ms  twoSum_Right_Said_Fred
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVKxboMwEN35ilsicEPSAm3VIrF06NalGVGEnGASR9ggY5Tm6@nZkKRRiNQht9g@vXv33vnqg95WMnqrVdcVqhKguWBcAxd1pTQoVjOqHSdnBeh9tWhF9kGVOmRfVPKy2nuyFQ0kkEY@hD5ESx80VRumMfdKYgcwikoB9wGRAXAJDC9MUc1s7YA54nYWF17jUj4NYmTH40@JCV701NO@MkkGBZcoE4rpVklIUcxueeHpm2@2OltQnmefiuX3dnW0dDZyBwuGbM5lzn5MS5TJsT4gaKxo5drIH/sw/4ZlrEKhptIItQx991pxqT2T8Ahx@hdxhovbCFqWgJOkbalhTRsWu@QWFcpcMYXCgicTNmfWzWhtcNtw8P2@2Xb@gE/6A5uf5Tx47uQ5B9mACxPwNDweyR8gYO/ETl2b9paf@FbGPMskFSzLrn3I5AUVnQxIVGQSzrAIJW@0p6jc4PfCDEJCcNbpLPBhFizHQOTmEMYNl1SschpboN0gZA7JaQTBmHtxcm9MR/823XW/)):

```
from timeit import repeat

def twoSum_Barry_Manilow(nums = [3, 2, 3], target = 6):
    for i, num1 in enumerate(nums):
        for j, num2 in enumerate(nums[i+1:], i+1):
            if num1 + num2 == target:
                return [i, j]

def twoSum_Right_Said_Fred(nums = [3, 2, 3], target = 6):
    for i, num1 in enumerate(nums):
        for num2 in nums[i+1:]:
            if num1 + num2 == target:
                return [i, nums.index(num2, i + 1)]

funcs = twoSum_Barry_Manilow, twoSum_Right_Said_Fred

for func in funcs:
    print(func())
print()

print('small default case:')
for func in funcs:
    number = 100000
    times = sorted(repeat(func, number=number))
    print(*('%4d ns ' % (t / number * 1e9) for t in times), func.__name__)
print()

print('n=5000 case:')
n = 5000
nums = list(range(n - 2)) + [-1, -1]
nums = list(range(n))
for func in funcs:
    times = sorted(repeat(lambda: func(nums, -2), number=1))
    print(*('%4d ms ' % (t * 1e3) for t in times), func.__name__)
print()
```

Comment: if you wanted to improve the time further you could replace the nested `for loop`s, with `for num1, num2 in combinations(nums, 2):` and at the start of file `from itertools import combinations`, then you also need to do the indexing a bit differently with the first number and that would be using sth like `i = nums.index(num1)` before the `return` statement, also you shouldn't use `mutable objects` as default arguments

Comment: @Matiiss Right, I think I've even done it that `combinations` way before. Don't really want to change it further, though, mainly I just did this because Barmar's false claims about `index()` bother me.